# Unable to upload the talend job zip file from windows machine to tac through metaservlet api

Tags: talend

Unable to call the associatePreGeneratedJob api endpoint. Keep getting the 180 error. Trying to upload the zip file from Windows machine to a tac server that is running on docker container

### Talend documentation:

### Command: associatePreGeneratedJob

Description             : Create a new execution task with a pre-generated zip file
- targetConductor: could be [JOBCONDUCTOR, BIGDATA_STREAMING]. "JOBCONDUCTOR" is the default value.
- importType: the position where select the zip file from; 'Nexus' or 'File', default value is 'File'
Requires authentication : true
Since                   : 5.2
Sample                  : 
{
  "actionName": "associatePreGeneratedJob",
  "active": true,
  "authPass": "admin",
  "authUser": "admin@company.com",
  "contextName": "Default",
  "description": "task1's description",
  "executionServerName": "serv1",
  "filePath": "'/home/talend/generatedJob.zip'",
  "importType": "Nexus",
  "logLevel": "Info",
  "nexusArtifactId": "test",
  "nexusGroupId": "org.example",
  "nexusRepository": "snapshots",
  "nexusVersion": "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "onUnknownStateJob": "WAIT",
  "pauseOnError": false,
  "taskName": "task1",
  "timeout": 3600
}
Specific error codes    : 
       180: file is not a valid file or not exist

### 181: nexus parameters may be not correct

Reference:
Talend Metaservlet api documentation: https://help.talend.com/reader/oYf9gKhmYrkWCiSua4qLeg/SLiAyHyDTjuznLR_F~MiQQ

Have tried this.
MetaServletCaller.bat --tac-url=http://localhost:8080/org.talend.administrator/ --json-params="{"actionName":"associatePreGeneratedJob","active": true,"authPass": "admin","authUser": "admin@company.com","contextName": "Default","description":"New","executionServerName": "test", "filePath": "'C:\Users\st\Desktop\JOb\t1.zip'","logLevel": "Info","onUnknownStateJob": "WAIT","importType": "File","pauseOnError": false, "taskName": "task_new","taskType": "Normal","timeout": 3600}"

Job zip file should be uploaded to tac server

Answer (score 0):

Going to the network logs and capturing the api request helped to decipher where the files were getting stored in the container. If zip files are somehow sent to that location in the container, that path can be passed to the api request
Ex path in container : /usr/local/tomcat/temp/test.zip